# File Upload : EMAXBUFFER Error

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, error-handling, npm, buffer

I am trying to process[*encoding and encryption*] an **audio file** and then **upload to S3** using *npm* module **[knox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knox)**

Its getting processed but *before getting uploaded to S3*, its poping up this **error**:

> Error: EMAXBUFFER: An Upstream (`audio`) timed out before it was
>   plugged into a receiver. It was still unused after waiting 4500ms. You
>   can configure this timeout by changing the `maxTimeToBuffer` option.

I tried uploading different sized files, but its happening for even a small file.
I had tried every possible solution available or suggested by people over Internet and most of the places, its for [Skipper-S3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skipper-s3), no where I could find for KNOX.

It will be great if someone can help me out in this.

I referred to some [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957779/emaxbuffer-error) on stack as well, but still in vain.